# Unable to resolve identifier stoi

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to parse the string into an integer and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
int s = std::stoi(input);
```

This will not build and raises the error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of the 'cin' statement.

Comment: I did this and now it says 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: Then you'll need to include <string> and be sure to tell your compiler to use c++11 (I believe all versions of gcc before 5.0 need that).

Answer (score 2):

Older version of C++ compiler does not support stoi. for the older version you can use the following code snippet to convert a string to integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    int s = std::atoi(input.c_str());
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

otherwise use c++ compiler version higher than C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::stringstream`. C string utilities are bad for `std::string`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  int num1, num2;
  std::string line("5 6");
  std::stringstream ss(line);
  ss >> num1 >> num2;
  std::cout << "num1 is " << num1 << " and num2 is " << num2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/0BFjjs).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to include string.

Aside from that, keep in mind that stoi may throw, so you'll want to encapsulate its usage in a try/catch block, like so:

```
using namespace std;
try
{
   string stringy= "25";
   int x= stoi(string);
   cout<<"y is: "<<y<<endl;
}
catch(invalid_argument& e)
{
   cout<<"you entered something that does NOT evaluate to an int"<<endl;
}
```

Try this out, if you provide stoi with say "x25", it'll throw, if not it'll go through. If you do not use this try/catch syntax, the program will crash the moment stoi throws.

Also, it seems stoi is smart enough to stop parsing if it detects something that doesn't evaluate, so "25x" will work out fine, it'll simply omit the x. But "x25" will throw.

While exception handling wasn't directly part of your question, I thought it wise to mention.